# Refer subnet block name in another resource block of terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a vnet resource as defined in terraform registry.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "example" {
  name                = "example-security-group"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-network"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  dns_servers         = ["10.0.0.4", "10.0.0.5"]

  subnet {
    name           = "subnet1"
    address_prefix = "10.0.1.0/24"
  }

  subnet {
    name           = "subnet2"
    address_prefix = "10.0.2.0/24"
    security_group = azurerm_network_security_group.example.id
  }

  tags = {
    environment = "Demo"
  }
}
```

Now, I am creating another resource called example and I want to refer name of subnet2 in it. How can I do it?

```
resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "myagw"{
  mysubnet = azurerm_virtual_network.example.subnet[1].name // I need to have subnet2 in the place. Is it possible?
}
```

Comment: While there is syntax to refer to each `subnet` block within that resource, it would be easier and better practices in general to use https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/subnet. Also it is unclear what you want to accomplish with `azurerm_application_gateway` as there is no `mysubnet` parameter for that resource.

Answer (score 1):

Create the subnet using its own resource.
Check the following:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-vnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "example-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
  }
}
```

Then you can use it like azurerm_subnet.example.name

Though I can see there is not attribute named `mysubnet` in azurerm_application_gateway resource. [Ref](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/application_gateway)